# Recovering linked account

Tags: discussion, accounts

My friend has an account on the Stack. He had an account opened through with Google. The google account he used was provided by an institution and they terminated the account. Since he never set up a password, he can no longer log in.

He has become so frustrated that he stopped visiting the site. I want to convince him to come back.

Can I get his account recovered?

Comment: My first instinct is consistent with my research: the answer is for your friend to [contact the Stack Overflow team](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237449/lost-my-stack-overflow-account-when-i-trashed-my-e-mail-address) for help. They'll need him to verify his ownership of the account in some way, but they'll have to work that out with him.

Comment: There must be an easier way to go.